Access docker container from jupyter server running on machine "outside container"?
I created a docker image running on my machine. I also have a Jupyter server running outside the container for code development. Is there a way for my jupyter server to access the contents of the container?
I was thinking if it is possible to setup some accessibility of my running jupyter server when I run the docker image... Is there something to do there? or should I set this up after I run the docker image?
Thanks!

What do you mean with "access"? Is that a network service in your docker container? Do you need access to the file system? Add some details. Both if possible with volume mounts or port mapping.

A container has an isolated filesystem, if that's your question; a non-container process can't access the container's filesystem, nor vice versa.

Sounds like you want to mount a local directory as a volume on your docker container. Whenever you edit a file on your local machine in that directory (e.g. in Jupyter) it will be visible to the docker container and vice-versa.
docker run --name my-container -v $(pwd)/my-directory:/home/my-directory -d my-image

source: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/docker-mount-volume-guide-how-to-mount-a-local-directory/
